# angular-material working with phonegap on Android 5.0 but not on Android 4.2

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Angularjs Material design Not working in Phone-Gap android4.2 and 4.4 , but working 5.0 please help me anyone if know the answer

```
<md-toolbar style="height: 64px;">
        <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span>Sign In</span>
        </h2>
    </md-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.1 to 4.4 isnt supported. Use crosswalk plugin and everything will work as it should.

https://crosswalk-project.org

> What is the Crosswalk Project for?
>
> If you are a developer working with web technologies, the Crosswalk Project enables you to deploy a web application with its own dedicated runtime. This means three things:
>
> You can distribute your web application via app stores.
> Your application won't break in whatever ancient webviews or browsers your audience is using, as you control the runtime and its upgrade cycle.
> You can build applications without worrying so much about runtime differences and quirks: you only have one runtime to deal with.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.